# Torque due to forces acting over a surface area

Tags: torque

As a footnote in page-3 of Jaan Kalda's notes on [mechanics](https://www.ioc.ee/%7Ekalda/ipho/meh_ENG2.pdf), he writes if we have a force acting over an area, then we would find total torque by integrating 'something' over the total area. I'm not sure what this 'something' is, anyways, he also writes about the effective application point of forces as

$$ d \Pi = \Pi(\vec{r_1} + d \vec{r_1} , \vec{r_2} + d \vec{r_2} ...) -  \Pi(\vec{r_1}  , \vec{r_2}  ...)$$

This formula is not really transparent to me as to what really the idea behind it is. Could someone explain what is going on here/ redirect me to something which explains this concept?

Edit: Aaah I just realized the formula is not related to the torque thing. I would edit it out but someone answered with that aspect in context.

Answer (score 0):

The stament  about the effective action point is footnote 8. The equation on the next line with the $\Pi$'s is footnote 9 from "fact 8" on the next page. It has nothing to do with the action point!

Incidently his "fact 7" about torque equalling rate of change of angular momentum is not correct in general. This only applies when one is taking moemnts about a point at rest, or about the center of mass, or about a point moving parallel to the centre of mass. It is incorrect in all other circumstances.

I would be careful in relying on theses notes!

Comment: I did not ever know this, how would it look like if the point wasn't at rest? Secondly what about the area thing?

Comment: See my old answer to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559157/how-to-find-origin-for-angular-momentum/559176#559176