# Confusion In rotational dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

Since angular acceleration is absolute on entire body (correct me if i am wrong), can we choose an arbitrary axis to calculate the torque and then calculate the angular acceleration?  (Regardless of how the calculations be difficult.)  If it is possible, what will be the meaning of the calculations and torque values, since we have choosen an axis of rotation other than the actual axis of rotation?

Comment: This might help - [Axis of rotation of a spool unwinding and falling under gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/780490/37364)

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/776222/392

Comment: @JohnAlexiou , i saw your comment and it is nicely explained, but i have a question can we use this equations with oriented axis of rotation ( given that we can get the moment of inertia tensor) because your comment is about arbitrary parallel axis only

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim - yes, if it works for a general $\vec{\omega}$ is also works for a specific axis, by decomposing rotation into an axis and a speed $$\vec{\omega} = \hat{z} \dot{\theta}$$ In a more general situation, like that of a robotic arm you have a sequence of each link in the robot with $$\vec{\omega}_i = \vec{\omega}_{i-1} + \hat{z}_i \dot{\theta}_i$$ where the subscripts describe the link #.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between torque and rotational acceleration is depended on the moment of inertia.  If you calculate about a different axis, you will get a different moment, and thus a different torque.  This should not be too surprising if you consider a tool such as a socket wrench.  The torque is highest when you consider an axis with the longest moment arm -- where we put the socket.

To consider the motion of a rigid body, one does not just need to consider torques.  One must also consider linear forces.  If you do the equations of motion about the "wrong" point, you can still get a valid answer, but the handling of these linear forces will be more computationally difficult.  If you do them about the "right" point, they get easier.

For a free-falling body, doing the computations about the center of mass typically provides the easiest calculations.  If there are constraints, then they may capture the "best" axis for you to rotate about.  In the case of the socket wrench, there's complex forces and torques between the bolt head and the socket which sum to zero if we calculate the rotation about the axis of the bolt-head/socket.  You can do the calculation about another point, such as the middle of the wrench.  But if you do, there will be linear forces and accelerations at work, and worse, they will be linear accelerations that change over time as the wrench moves and rotates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Euler_equations

Comment: I found this on wikipedia does this complicated formula in section (any reference frame) will do the calculations you talking about?

Comment: Yes, those are indeed the calculations.  They're slightly more complicated than necessary because they are written in matrix form.   When doing more advanced calculations, it can often be convenient to use matrices, even if they're a little more complicated than necessary, because it lets you use all of the matrix tools, like taking the inverse of a matrix.  It makes it a bit easier to manipulate the equations cleanly.

Answer (score 7):

The axis of rotation is arbitrary. But generally speaking, if you pick a random point, the result will be a combination of rotation and translation.

Let's consider a linearly moving particle to show how this works. At $t=0$ this particle is located $d$ above the origin and has velocity $v$ to the right, i.e.
\begin{align}
\vec r_0&=\begin{pmatrix}0\\d\end{pmatrix}\\
\vec v_0&=\begin{pmatrix}v\\0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
If you pick the point $(0,d)$ as rotation point, you will get angular momentum $L=0$ which should make sense. If instead you pick the origin, you get $L=rp\sin\theta=mvd$. How does this particle have angular momentum around the origin? It's not rotating!

Actually, it is. The length from the origin is just increasing in the right amount and the rotation rate is slowing down the right way such that the overall motion is straight.

To see this let's write the angular momentum in terms of angular quantities using $L=I\omega$, where $I=mr^2$ and $\omega=v_\perp/r$. Here $v_\perp=v\sin\theta$ is the velocity component normal to the vector $\vec r$. We can use the following identities to calculate $I$ and $v_\perp$:
\begin{align}
\vec r(t)&=\begin{pmatrix}vt\\d\end{pmatrix}\\
\vec v(t)&=\begin{pmatrix}v\\0\end{pmatrix}\\
v^2&=v_\perp^2+v_\parallel^2\\
v_\parallel(t)&=\frac{\vec v\cdot \vec r}r
\end{align}

After some work you get
$$v_\perp=\frac{v}{\sqrt{1+\frac{v^2t^2}{d^2}}}$$

So finally we can conclude
\begin{align}
I(t)&=mr^2=m(v^2t^2+d^2)\\
\omega(t)&=v_\perp/r=\frac{v}{\sqrt{v^2t^2+d^2}}
\end{align}

As an exercise, you can show that you recover $L=mdv$. So in conclusion, we can view straight line motion as a rotation with increasing moment of inertia and decreasing angular velocity. Similarly, you can view torque about an arbitrary point as a complicated combination of angular acceleration. But there is an exception. When you choose the point of rotation as the *actual* axis of rotation of your object, the problem becomes *simpler* instead of harder. For a merry-go-round you pick the axle. For a body in free-fall, you pick the center of mass. For a see-saw you pick the axle/point of support. Because those are points where the object rotates about.

Answer (score 4):

The key issue is that rate of change of angular momentum of a body about a point P is equal to the  torque about P only if one of the following is true:

1. the point P is at rest
2. the point P is the centre of mass of the body.
3. the point P is moving parallel to the centre of mass.

This has probably been answered many time on SE. For example see here: [How to find Origin for Angular Momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559157/how-to-find-origin-for-angular-momentum/559176#559176)